# common elements between two collections in java

Tags: java

```
  public class Task1 {

     public static void main(String[] args) {

        List<Task> mainList = new ArrayList<>();
        Task e = new Task();
        e.setId(1);
        e.setName("shiva");
        mainList.add(e);

        e.setId(2);
        e.setName("Jyothi");
        mainList.add(e);

        e.setId(3);
        e.setName("Dinnu");
        mainList.add(e);

        //System.out.println(mainList);

        List<Task> subList = new ArrayList<>();

        Task e1 = new Task();
        e1.setId(1);
        e1.setName("shiva");
        subList.add(e1);


        List<Task> finalList = getFinalList(mainList, subList);
    }
```

...

```
    private static List<Task> getFinalList(List<Task> mainList, List<Task> subList) {
        List<Task> finalList = new ArrayList<>();

        System.out.println("final List: "+mainList.retainAll(subList));

        for(Task o : mainList){

            for(Task o1 : subList){

                if (o.equals(o1)){

                                  finalList.add(o);
                }
            }
        }

        System.out.println(finalList);
        return finalList;
```

But Still im unable to get the common elements..may i knw wat im making fault.

Comment: Could you show your Task class? Also you are modifying the same object three times and adding it in your first list, so the two lists have no elements in common. I.e `mainList` contains `[3 Dinnu, 3 Dinnu, 3 Dinnu]` and `taskList` contains `[1 shiva]`

Comment: @user3351552  feedback is good thing when people are trying to help you . Did any of the below solve your problem(yes,no, maybe).

Comment: possible duplicate of [Please tell me how to write and algorithm in java that can return the common elements in two collections?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22016368/please-tell-me-how-to-write-and-algorithm-in-java-that-can-return-the-common-ele)

Comment: lol @ Raedwald same user same question !!

Comment: Im sorry for writing the same question again..I wanted to put it in clear way comparing to my OLD post.@NullSoulException and @raedwald

Comment: @user3351552 While it's good that you want to make the question clear, *always* favor editing a question over posting a second question for the same issue.

Answer (score 2):

It's a fairly straightforward solution:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    List<String> list1 = new ArrayList<String>() {
        {
            add("string 1");
            add("string 2");
            add("string 3");
            add("string 4");
        }
    };
    List<String> list2 = new ArrayList<String>() {
        {
            add("string 4");
            add("string 5");
            add("string 3");
            add("string 6");
            add("string 3");
        }
    };

    Set<String> hash1 = new HashSet<>(list1);
    Set<String> hash2 = new HashSet<>(list2);

    hash1.retainAll(hash2);

    System.out.println(hash1);
}
```

This prints

> [string 4, string 3]

Most of the code is setting up the values. Don't forget to implement `.equals(Object o)` and `.hashCode()` in your custom class.

Comment: that is  "fairly straightforward' @Jeroen Vannevel .....@user3351552 did anyof these help... Or you are too busy posting the question elsewhere like http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22016368/please-tell-me-how-to-write-and-algorithm-in-java-that-can-return-the-common-ele

Comment: no sir..."final List: true
[]" this is the output im getting

Comment: That's because you're not doing what I wrote. `retainAll()` returns a `boolean` value and modifies the collection. You have to call `retainAll()` first and then add another line to print the values of the collection.

Comment: k please tel me for object type that is of type <Task>..if I take any list of type int or string im able to return the common elements but when i tried to compare two objects im having this problm..

Comment: @user3351552: have you overriden `.equals` and `.hashcode`?

Comment: s i did..@JeroenVannevel ...im not sure what im missing

Comment: @user3351552: please edit your post to show your current code. Include the `Task` class and how you do the combining.

Answer (score 1):

You need to write an appropriate equals() method for the Task class.  You created two different Task objects, and the default equals() implementation won't work in this case.  Write a custom equals() that compares the id and name appropriately!

edit:  Also, it looks like you aren't actually creating three Tasks for the first list.  You create one new Task and then change its values.  If you print out the size of the mainList after you are finished setting it up, it probably has the same Task object inside three times.

Answer (score 0):

One possibility is to use  Set data structures (where you don't allow duplications), you can find the union between two sets very easily. Google Guava for example provides that.

Answer (score 0):

You modified same instance every time mainList has only one object

recreate it like this

```
    List<Task> mainList = new ArrayList<Task>();
    Task e = new Task();
    e.setId(1);
    e.setName("shiva");
    mainList.add(e);

    Task e1 = new Task();
    e1.setId(2);
    e1.setName("Jyothi");
    mainList.add(e1);

    Task e12 = new Task();
    e12.setId(3);
    e12.setName("Dinnu");
    mainList.add(e12);

    //System.out.println(mainList);

    List<Task> subList = new ArrayList<Task>();

    Task e13 = new Task();
    e13.setId(1);
    e13.setName("shiva");
    subList.add(e13);
```

and remove this line ...

```
      System.out.println("final List: "+mainList.retainAll(subList));
```

Use

```
      for(Task o : mainList){

        for(Task o1 : subList){

            if( ( o.getId() == o1.getId() ) && o.getName().equals(o1.getName()) ){
                                finalList.add(o);
      }     
        }
    }

    System.out.println(finalList);
    return finalList;
```

and implement hasCode() method in Task (If you using eclipse IDE means press alt+shift+s -> generate hash code and equals() it automatically generates)

Comment: I wouldn't rely on hashcode to test if the two objects have the same state. `a equals b => a.hashCode = b.hashCode`, but the reverse is not always true (you can have collisions with your hash function)

Comment: @user3351552 i checked this this return one object

Comment: @user3351552 have you checked?

Comment: @user3351552 are you try the above one?

Comment: @saran: thank you mate it worked.But I have one doubt here we are directly comparing the properties.Suppose what if we have many properties in the object do we have to follow the same logic else how to how to compare???

Comment: @user3351552 use hashCode() and equals() method.

Answer (score 0):

I see one thing definitely wrong, and one thing potentially wrong here.

First, When you're done adding to your first list, the list contains three references to the same Task instance. Essentially, you have three Task references in the list that all have id=3 and name="dinnu". I'm guessing you probably intended to do this instead:

```
List<Task> mainList = new ArrayList<>();
Task e = new Task();
e.setId(1);
e.setName("shiva");
mainList.add(e);

e = new Task(); //Make a new instance
e.setId(2);
e.setName("Jyothi");
mainList.add(e);

e = new Task(); //Make a new instance
e.setId(3);
e.setName("Dinnu");
mainList.add(e);
```

Basically, since you forgot to make new instances, you were just changing the values on the same object instead of making new objects.

The second potential problem is that Java Collections will use the "equals()" method on your  Task Object to determine object equality. If you don't have one, it will just check to see if the Objects refer to the same object instance, rather than comparing the object's properties. Therefore, you might need to implement an equals() method on your Task object as well if you don't already have one.

If you fix those things, than calling mainList.retainAll(subList) will remove all elements in mainList that are not present in subList. (finalList will not be necessary - that call will simply edit mainList)

If you would like to preserve mainList instead of editing it, then do this instead:

```
List<Task> finalList = new ArrayList<>(mainList); //Copy main into finalList
finalList.retainAll(subList); //remove elements that are not present in subList
```

Answer (score 0):

One way to do it is by using hashtables instead of list . Since you have String and integer hasgtable will be ideal solution for your scenario and then you can use some thing like this to find the intersecting values from the two hashtables.

```
Hashtable<String, Integer> inersect = new Hashtable<String, Integer>(hashtable1);
inersect.keySet().retainAll(hashtable2.keySet());
System.out.println(inersect);
```

Answer (score 0):

equals method for your custom object Task needs to be implemented by either making the Task class implement Comparable Class.

```
class Task implements Comparable<Task>{

@Override
public int compareTo(Task o) {
    return (o.getId()==this.getId() && o.getName().equals(this.getName());
}
//other class functions
}
```